# All shortest paths for weighted graphs with networkx?

Tags: graph, shortest-path, networkx, weighted

I have a graph composed by two different sets of edges. The first set is made by edges of weight 1 (list 1). The second set is made by edges of weight 2 (list 2). First, I create the graph with networkx and then use add_edges_from to add list 1 and list 2. I would like to compute all the shortest paths in this weighted graph. Basically I'm looking for the analogous of "all_shortest_paths" but with weights (looks like "dijkstra" module does not allow you to know all the possible routes between a given source and a given target). If I try to use "all_shortest_path" with weighted links (3-tuples, the two nodes and the weight) I get the error . Can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I noticed that my explanation is completely unclear, I'm sorry. The admin might want to delete previous comments (no problem with it, it was my bad). Basically I have this, with edges_W1 which is a list of lines (each lines has 3 entries, two for nodes and 1 for the weight of the link connecting them)   W=nx.Graph() W.add_weighted_edges_from(edges_W1) . If I do print nx.all_shortest_paths(W,0,1) I get "generator object all_shortest_paths at 0x9b8ed9c between <>. 0 and 1 of course were just an example

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example to show how all_shortest_paths() works

```
import networkx as nx
import StringIO
edges = StringIO.StringIO("""
a b 1
a bb 1
b c 2
bb c 2
c d 1
a d 10""")
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(edges, nodetype=str)
print list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, 'a', 'd', weight='weight'))
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'bb', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: FYI, ``nx.all_shortest_paths`` use dijkstra method to get the ``pred`` and ``dist`` of each vertex, so if the graph contains negative weighted edge(s), that will not give the correct result.